# When will one use Workbooks.Close in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

It looks like any code after Workbooks.Close will not be executed (simply because all workbooks are closed). But when does one need to put this code at the end of his program?

Comment: When you want to close your workbooks after the macro finished.  Seems pretty obvious....

Comment: But you can still see the blank grey excel application after running this. It's not exactly like closing the workbook manually. Who would want it?@MátéJuhász

Comment: In other words, how can I also close the blank grey Excel window?@MátéJuhász

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Workbooks.Close` closes all open workbooks. It doesn't close the Excel application.

If any one of the open workbooks is not saved then you will get a prompt when you try to use `Workbooks.Close`

> In other words, how can I also close the blank grey Excel window?@MátéJuhász – Nicholas 3 mins ago

It is very simple actually. Loop through all the open workbooks and save them and then instead of closing the workbooks, simply quit the application. The workbooks will automatically close and so will the application. Here is an example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wb As Workbook

    For Each wb In Workbooks
        wb.Save
        DoEvents
    Next wb

    Application.Quit
End Sub
```

> But you can still see the blank grey excel application after running this. It's not exactly like closing the workbook manually. Who would want it?@MátéJuhász – Nicholas 10 mins ago

Well, I for one would definitely want it. I usually have 4 to 5 workbooks open. And I want to open a 6th one but do not want the other 5 open so I use `Workbooks.Close`. This way the unwanted workbooks are closed and I still have the application open for me to open the new workbook.

The beauty of `Workbooks.Close` is that you can run this command from the Immediate Window as well :)

Comment: Another interesting use case is when automating Excel from another application, one might want to close the workbooks but keep the handle to the excel application for further work.

Comment: True that. I have never used `Workbooks.Close` other than the Immediate Window as I mentioned above. Never needed to :D. I always explicitly closed each of my objects

Comment: For "still have the application open for me to open the new workbook", this cannot be automated using VBA code, right? Since `ThisWorkbook` will be closed too, then where do you store the code `Workbooks.Open` after `Workbooks.Close`?

Comment: `....and I still have the application open for me to open the new workbook Manually`... This is what I meant :) @Nicholas

Comment: Thanks. Should I type `?Workbooks.Close` to use in the immediate window? Why I got `Complie error: Expected Function or variable`? Another question is what does `DoEvents` do here?

Comment: @Nicholas: `1` No. use it without the "?" `2` Doevents gives Excel time while it tries to save the workbook.

Comment: Any harm if I don't use `DoEvents`?

Comment: Yes, there have been moments where Excel has crashed on me :D @Nicholas

Comment: re: Application.Quit - should that be Excel.Quit?